# Bash - Source a file with "/"

Tags: file, bash, scripting

I have a cache in the filesystem which I implemented this way.

1. To store a value I do something like

   ```
   echo ""$KEY1"_"$KEY2"="$VALUE" >> $CACHE_DIR/$INDEX.cache
   ```
2. To get a value, first I source the cache file:

   ```
   source $CACHE_DIR/$INDEX.cache
   ```

   and then I echo the `"$KEY1"_"$KEY2"`

Cache example:

```
foo1_foo2=wohohhowwho
```

The problem with this, is that I have some keys that have a "/" in it, so when I have this:

```
foo3_foo/4=wohohhowwho
```

and source the file, it says

```
cache/15637.cache: line 1: foo3_foo/4=wohohhowwho: No such file or directory
```

because of the `/`.

Is there an option to the source command to not search in the path for files and only take in count the content as vars? I could escape the `/`, but is there another way?

Comment: You seem to be confusing bash scripts with a storage mechanism...

Comment: I'm not confusing anything, I use a cache that works fine for me. I only have one case with problems. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to ``sanitize'' you key as bash only support for variable name: letter, digit and the underline character.

```
KEY1=${KEY1//\//_}
KEY2=${KEY2//\//_}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way since `/` is not allowed as a character in bash variables.